# Handle SIGABRT in Electron.js/Node.js application

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, electron, node-gyp

I am trying to create a node js native addon using node-gyp and I use nbind to import the addon into my electron.js application. I am using a 3rd library to build this addon but unfortunately, the library exits the execution block using SIGABRT which then creates trouble for my electron application. After calling a particular method the 3rd party library aborts the execution by sending a SIGABRT with exit code 134 which makes my electron application go white screen.

I do feel that the further execution of the code is blocked and electron DevTools gets disconnected and the screen goes totally blank. None of the events in node.js works after this.

How do I handle this SIGABRT in electron/node.js without making my application go haywire?

Thanks and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The `SIGABRT` is most certainly the result of a bug in your code that you have to fix, so that the `SIGABRT` is not issued. A `SIGABRT` is for e.g. issued if a `assert` test failed. If this happens while using a library then this indicates that you made an error while using that library, that error might be something that could be not solvable out of the perspective of that library, which might exit the program out of that reason.

Comment: @t.niese I am using LIBMTP_Set_File_Name method of the libmtp library to rename a file and the method throws a malloc error despite doing everything just right. This error occurs depending on the device used. Is there any way to handle SIGABRT in cpp or node.js?

Comment: Again a `SIGABRT` is normally only issued if the library detects a not recoverable state. Handling the `SIGABRT` means to figure out what you did wrong when you use that library, and fixing your code. Even if you would catch that signal and ignore it your whole application most certainly is in an undefined and completely unstable state from that point. And how would you try to solve that state if the library does not know how to do that.